# Building Kraken2 Databases Errors

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

Currently running a metagenomic analysis of transcriptome reads using kraken2. Currently running into issues installing the required databases

Buildind kraken2 database code:

```
kraken2-build --download-library archaea --db archaea_DB
kraken2-build --download-library viral --db viral_DB
kraken2-build --download-library bacteria --db bacteria_DB
kraken2-build --download-library human --db human_DB
kraken2-build --download-library fungi --db fungi_DB
kraken2-build --download-library protozoa --db protozoa_DB
```

Errors:

```
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution

rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]

Error downloading assembly summary file for archaea, exiting.
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution

rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]
Error downloading assembly summary file for viral, exiting.
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]

Error downloading assembly summary file for bacteria, exiting.
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]
Error downloading assembly summary file for human, exiting.
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution

rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]
Error downloading assembly summary file for fungi, exiting.
rsync: getaddrinfo: ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov 873: Temporary failure in name resolution
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.6]
Error downloading assembly summary file for protozoa, exiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so some adjustments I made was that I had to manually change the source code files of kraken2 through my anaconda environment.

I don't recall exactly what the changes were (you can look them up yourselves), but to access the files you can run the `conda info -a` command to find the directory where your conda environments are located. For example: `find $(conda info -a) -name "rsync_from_ncbi.pl"`.

Once Files are edited then we can do the kraken2 process. **The Errors I had was actually issues with the connection with the server (don't know why, but that's how it worked)**. **Just wait for like 10 minutes or more and run the code and it should work.**

Step 1: create a directory for the database

`mkdir database`

Step 2: Download taxonomy data to the database

`kraken2-build --download-taxonomy --db database`

Step 3: Download microbial data for the database

`kraken2-build --download-library bacteria --db database`

Step 4: Once the data is loaded to the library, build the database

`kraken2-build --build --db database`

These should be all the commands needed for kraken2